# A nonlinear system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Given that:
$$2c-3bt=-358,\\2c+3b+4t=-102,\\-2ct+b=-318$$
find the value of $2(c+bt)$: is it required to find $c,b,$ and $t$ individually? If we must find them separately, then how? By WA, this system has 3 real solutions. I do not know how to solve it.

Any help/hint would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Is your question about whether you have to find $c,b,t$ individually or just how to solve the system?

Comment: @R.J.Etienne my question how to solve (by anyway), not necessary to be solved by finding $c,b,t$ separately. THANKS DEAR.

Comment: I'd be interested if someone knows any method other than solving an equation for one variable then substituting in the next etc.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation Ok to begin with which equation? which variable?

Comment: @DietrichBurde , that is exactly what I got by WA, "resultants", what do you mean? PLEASE DEAR, tell me what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the system by using resultants, but I still believe that a solution by substitution is so easy. First we have $b=2ct-318$, and then we have
$t=-\frac{1}{3c+2}(c - 426)$. This gives
$$
(3c^2 + 1332c + 14540)(c + 14)=0
$$
and we are done.

By the way, $2(c+tb)$ is not always equal for the three solutions. For the case $c=-14$ we have
$$
(b,c,t)=(-10,-14,-11)
$$
so that $2(c+tb)=192$.

Comment: Thanks dear, almost understood, except for $t=\dots$? how did you get it?

Comment: Just from the second equation (after we have substituted $b$ from the third equation).